# Laravel 5 cronjob Cpanel

Tags: php, laravel

I'am trying to develop a cron job for a command to send email. Trying the command by myself in the console works perfectly. But when a set a cron job in CPANEL its not workingrs.

i got this message : [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

I am using Laravel 5, can anyone help please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proc\_open and Capifony issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501606/proc-open-and-capifony-issue)

Comment: check this out
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911737/laravel4-composer-install-got-proc-open-not-available-error

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419702/laravel-5-2-the-process-class-relies-on-proc-open-which-is-not-available-on-yo/45419955#45419955