# Laravel 5.2: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, cron, cpanel

I use cron job to do some CRUD operation using laravel Task Scheduling. On localhost and on my Share-Hosting server it worked fine for months until recently I keep getting this error when I run cron job on my Share-Hosting server. I did not make any changes to the code on my Share-Hosting server.

```
[2017-07-14 09:16:02] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.' in /home/xxx/xx/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:144
Stack trace:
```

But on localhost it works fine. Based on my finding online I have tried the following.

1. Contacted my hosting company to remove proc_open form disable PHP functions.
2. Hosting company provided custom php.ini file. I remove all disable_functions
3. Share-Hosting Server was restarted and cache was cleared

**None of this fixed the issue**. I am not sure of what next to try because the same project works fine on different Share-Hosting Server.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After many weeks of trying to resolve this error. The following fixes worked

1. Upgrade project from Laravel 5.2 to 5.4
2. On CPanel using "Select Php version"  set **PHP version to 7**
3. Or on CPanel using "MultiPHP Manager" set PHP version to ***ea-php70***

Now, cron job runs smoothly. I hope this helps someone.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: laravel 6 is my version

Comment: Not working for me, Laravel Framework 6.18.2 and PHP version ea-php73

Comment: hi, could you show me the command please. I can't get the jobs to work in my cpanel. I also have Laravel 7 and Cpanel and I tested it this way: /opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /home/brooklyn/Sistema/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1

Comment: This fix served to me. I'm running Laravel 9 with PHP 8.1. PHP version must match both in "Select Php version" and "MultiPHP Manager".

Comment: I had the same error and it's because I forgot to change the cron command from `/usr/local/bin/ea-php74 /home/xxx/laravel/current/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1` to `/usr/local/bin/ea-php80 /home/xxx/laravel/current/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1` when I upgrade the php version on "MultiPHP Manager". Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 12):

## Laravel 6 and higher (proc_open Error)

It is because of Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode
There is a workaround for this.

Publish flare config file
`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config`

and in `config/flare.php`

Set

```php
'collect_git_information' => false 
'reporting' => [
     'anonymize_ips' => true,
     'collect_git_information' => false,
     'report_queries' => true,
     'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
     'report_query_bindings' => true,
     'report_view_data' => true,
],
```

Comment: This is not working for me, Laravel Framework 6.18.2 and PHP version ea-php73

Comment: This is specific to a single library and should not be presented as a solution for general use.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this at your own risk:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -d "disable_functions=" /home/didappir/public_html/api/artisan schedule:run > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 3):

When Flare error reporting service enabled in debug mode you'll see this error

The solution is:

Publish flare config file

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config
```

in config/flare.php Set:

```
'reporting' => [
        'anonymize_ips' => true,
        'collect_git_information' => false,
        'report_queries' => true,
        'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
        'report_query_bindings' => true,
        'report_view_data' => true,
    ],



'send_logs_as_events' => false,
```

Answer (score 2):

For me removing cached version of config.php file solve problem(Laravel 6).
go to bootstrap/cache/config.php and remove file.
Also don't forget to change APP_URL to your domain address. PHP version should be as required by laravel version.

---

for shared host if you can't change php.ini, you should use laravel 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

if it is disabled you cannot run it

use phpinfo() to find out if it's disabled