# Laravel 6.18.2: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, cron, shared-hosting, proc-open

I used cron job to do some CRUD operation using laravel Task Scheduling. On localhost it is working fine. But on my shared host I keep getting this error.

```
2020-04-08 16:56:01] local.ERROR: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Process\\Exception\\LogicException(code: 0): The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation. at /home/deshiit/public_html/bangladesh-railway-server/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:143)
[stacktrace]
```

But on localhost it works fine. I contacted my hosting company to remove proc_open form disable PHP functions, but they can't. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419702/laravel-5-2-the-process-class-relies-on-proc-open-which-is-not-available-on-yo). But this solution is not working.

My PHP version is `ea-php73`. I also tried `ea-php71` and `ea-php72`.

In 
 `app/Console/Kernel.php` 
 if I add 
 `->withoutOverlapping();` after my command,

```php
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    Log::info('Cron Job Started 1.1');
    $schedule->command('outlier:data')
        ->everyMinute()
        ->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

then proc_open error gives only for one time and then

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
```

is getting called every minute but it is not executing the handle() funtion

```php
public function handle()
{
    Log::info('Cron Job Started 2.1 in Commands/FindOutlier.php');
}
```

But if I `Clear Cache`, again it gives the proc_open error for one time and then call the schedule funtion every minute.

Comment: By any chance, do you have Flare installed as a package?

Comment: @FelixLebel I used "php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config" to get flare.

Answer (score 0):

As per the commentd above, make sure Flare does not collect git information (It will try to open the git process and get branch and tag information).

In flare.php (config/flare.php):

```php
'collect_git_information' => false 
'reporting' => [
     'anonymize_ips' => true,
     'collect_git_information' => false,
     'report_queries' => true,
     'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
     'report_query_bindings' => true,
     'report_view_data' => true,
],
```

Now, this fixed it on my cPanel instance **only after I cleared the config and route caching**. Make sure you don't have anything cached and your OPCache is also cleared.

From what I see when I look at the code, Flare is the only library that calls upon `proc_open`. If this still doesn't work, try disabling debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

on cPanel goto multiPhPINI and enableing (allow_url_fopen)
this may fix problem