# Laravel 6.2: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, curl, php-curl, laravel-6.2

**Hello everybody**

I want get website address with form POST method and show meta tags in my page.

I try writing code with Laravel-6.2 PHP and I think everything OK but don't work. I think it's wrong in Curl code.

I found a similar error in [Laravel 5.2: The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419702/laravel-5-2-the-process-class-relies-on-proc-open-which-is-not-available-on-yo) but I have use php 7.2

Please help me find the mistake Thankful

**in Controller :**

```
public function MetaChecker(Request $request){
   $rules = array(
        'url' => 'required|url|max: 255',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha',
    );
    $messages = array(
        'url.required' => 'آدرس سایت معتبر نمی باشد.',
        'g-recaptcha-response.required' => 'کد امنیتی معتبر نمی باشد.',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make( $request->all(), $rules, $messages );
    if ( $validator->fails() )
    {
        return back()
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
    $domain = $request->input('url');
    $url = str_replace(array('Array', 'http://', 'https://', 'http://www.', 'https://www.', 'www.', '/'), '', strip_tags($domain));

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($data);
    $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

    $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
    {
        $meta = $metas->item($i);

        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'viewport')
            $viewport = $meta->getAttribute('content');
        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
            $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
    if ($data != 0) {

        return back()->with(
            'title', '<span>title : <strong class="en-font"> ' . $title . '</strong></span>')->with(
            'description', '<span>description : <strong class="en-font"> ' . $description . '</strong></span>')->with(
            'viewport', '<span>viewport : <strong class="en-font"> ' . $viewport . '</strong></span>');
    }else{
        return back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors(array('error' => 'آدرس سایت معتبر نمی باشد.'));
    }
}
```

**Error title:**

> LogicException
>
> The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation.

[image: Screenshot error]

Comment: What is your curent PHP version?

Comment: PHP version = 7.2

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436455/7117697) solution?

Comment: Also, are you positive that your local server is using the same php version (7.2)?

Comment: You mean, just work with php 7 version? other programs with curl writing that work properly with php version 7.2.

Comment: Yes, Tested by phpinfo()

Comment: I changed the version by AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php  and checked with phpinfo().
Was PHP Version 7.0.33  but this error : HTTP ERROR 500.